# How can I convert my Matlab GUI into Java?

Tags: java, matlab

Is there a way for me to convert the GUI and plot I created using matlab and convert it into Java code so that I can compile in java and use java to make further enhancements to the GUI?

I don't want to be tied down to Matlab, so I feel like I should move to a more open source environment?

Comment: The closest thing I can suggest is to export the data used to create the plot into some neutral format (e.g. ASCII csv) then import it wherever you like and plot it however you like..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Impossible.

Long answer explaining alternatives:
There is no way to convert MATLAB code automatically to JAVA code, such a Software does not exist. There are several ways to deploy MATLAB code to be called from JAVA. If a MATLAB installation is available on the target system, possibilities are listed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130539/how-to-run-matlab-code-from-java). If MATLAB is not available on your target system, possibilities are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045087/matlab-builder-ja-compile-matlab-into-a-java-jar-free-version). Note that the answers working with OCTAVE probably don't work with your GUI.

Not having MATLAB available on the target system and requiring GUI components, the MATLAB Builder JA probably the only choice for a automatic conversion to jar (not to java code). It is also a very expensive choice.

Comment: Thanks!
Then I'd like to ask... can I do matlab functionality in other languages? Like Java or C++? I want to be able to graph equations in 3d.

Comment: Your question is to broad to give a useful answer, especially one that fits into a comment. I am sure it can be done with Java or C++.