# How can I integrate a matlab project with existing jsp project

Tags: matlab, codeigniter, jsp

I'm going to do an image processing project using Matlab tool.but I'm in a need to integrate my project with an existing project,that existing project backend is made up with **JSP** and front end is based on **CodeIgniter** framework.Is it a good idea to use Matlab and C++ language?.please suggest some ideas or links to refer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607933/running-matlab-function-from-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130539/how-to-run-matlab-code-from-java . I assume you know how to use your own java classes in jsp.

Comment: yea,ill refer those links.thank you.